# Using nginx rewrite to remove date from URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

Unsure why this isn't working.

URL: `https://example.com/blog/2009/07/23/example`
redirect to: `https://example.com/example`

```
rewrite "^/blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)" /$5 permanent;
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, its just not doing anything, its not rewriting the URL

Comment: Just for some added, using a rewrite like this
`rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)" /$3/ permanent;` 
Works just fine on a URL with just example.com/2000/02/03/example in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out :)

```
location /blog {
rewrite "/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)" /$4 permanent;
}
```